# Display all columns after running df.columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6, label

I currently have 120 columns in my DataFrame. When I execute

```
df.columns
```

I get a truncated list, where I only see 20 instead of 120 columns:

```
Index(['Reporting_FI', 'Reporting_FI_identification',
   'Reporting_FI_identification_type', 'Reporting_FI_street_address_1',
   'Reporting_FI_street_address_2', 'Reporting_FI_city',
   'Reporting_FI_state', 'Reporting_FI_postal_code',
   'Reporting_FI_country_code', 'Transaction_date',
   ...
   'FI_country_code_3', 'FI_name_4', 'FI_branch_4', 'FI_identification_4',
   'FI_identification_type_4', 'FI_account_number_4', 'FI_city_4',
   'FI_state_4', 'FI_country_code_4', 'Additional_infomation_2'],
  dtype='object', length=120)
```

How do I adjust this to display all 120?

I am not looking for:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 120)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to convert to `list` before printing:

```
res = df.columns.tolist()

print(res)
```

Comment: Dang, why didn't I think of that! Very clever. Thanks.